# Aws oracle - how to give imp_full_database privilege?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In RDS-Oracle, when I try to import a full database or just a schema, I get the following error

```
Import: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sat Aug 22 07:40:53 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-31631: privileges are required
ORA-39122: Unprivileged users may not perform REMAP_SCHEMA remappings.
```

So I logged in to give the imp_full_database privilage, but that failed

```
SQL> grant imp_full_database  to expimp_user;
grant imp_full_database  to expimp_user
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20997: "IMP_FULL_DATABASE" grants not allowed
ORA-06512: at "RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN", line 51
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

How to give that privilege, so I can import?